# Error cargar objeto desde Local Storage

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema al llamar a un método de un objeto, cuando el objeto se carga desde Local Storage tras recargar la página. Pongo el código y explico un poco más el problema.

```
// VARIABLES
const formulario = document.getElementById('agregar-gasto');
var presupuesto, listaGastos = [];


// CLASES
class Presupuesto {

    constructor(presupuesto) {
        this.presupuesto = Number(presupuesto);
        this.restante = Number(presupuesto);
    }

    gasto(cantidad) {
        this.restante -= Number(cantidad);
    }
}

class Gasto {
    constructor(concepto, cuantia) {
        this.concepto = concepto;
        this.cuantia = cuantia;
    }
}


// EVENTOS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // comprobamos si es la primera ejecucion del programa o hay datos en LS
    if(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto') === null) {
        let intro = prompt('¿Cuál es el presupuesto?');
        console.log(typeof(presupuesto) );

    } else {
        presupuesto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto') );
        listaGastos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listaGastos') );
    }

    // actualizamos los datos en pantalla
    actualizaUI();
});

document.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevenimos la accion del HTML

    // leer del formulario de gastos
    const nombreGasto = document.querySelector('#gasto').value;
    const cantidadGasto = document.querySelector('#cantidad').value;

    // comprobar que los gastos no esten vacios, que la cantidad sea un numero positivo
    if(nombreGasto === '' || cantidadGasto === '' || isNaN(cantidadGasto) || cantidadGasto < 0) {
        imprimirMensaje('Hubo un error', 'error');
    } else {
        presupuesto.gasto(cantidadGasto);
        gasto = new Gasto(nombreGasto, cantidadGasto);
        listaGastos.push(gasto);
        imprimirMensaje('Gasto añadido', 'correcto');
        actualizaUI();
        actualizaLocalStorage();
    }
} ); 


// FUNCIONES
function actualizaUI() {
    const presupuestoSpan = document.querySelector('span#total');
    const restanteSpan = document.querySelector('span#restante');
    const gastosUl = document.querySelector('#gastos ul');

    // imprimir el presupuesto y el restante
    presupuestoSpan.innerHTML = `${presupuesto.presupuesto}`;
    restanteSpan.innerHTML = `${presupuesto.restante}`;

    // comprobar la clase del restante
    if((presupuesto.presupuesto / 4) > presupuesto.restante) {
        const restante = document.querySelector('.restante');
        restante.classList.remove('alert-success', 'alert-warning');
        restante.classList.add('alert-danger');
    } else if ((presupuesto.presupuesto / 2) > presupuesto.restante) {
        const restante = document.querySelector('.restante');
        restante.classList.remove('alert-success');
        restante.classList.add('alert-warning');  
    }

    // imprimir la lista de gastos
    listaGastos.forEach(function(gasto){
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center';
        li.innerHTML = 
            `${gasto.concepto} 
            <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'> $ ${gasto.cuantia} </span>
            `;

        // insertar al HTML
        gastosUl.appendChild(li);
    } );
}

function imprimirMensaje(mensaje, tipo) {
    const divMensaje = document.createElement('div');
    divMensaje.classList.add('text-center', 'alert');

    if(tipo === 'error') {
        divMensaje.classList.add('alert-danger');
    } else {
        divMensaje.classList.add('alert-success');
    }

    divMensaje.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mensaje));
    // insertar en el DOM
    document.querySelector('.primario').insertBefore(divMensaje, formulario);
    // quitar el alert despues de dos segundos
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.primario .alert').remove();
        formulario.reset();
    }, 2000);
}

function actualizaLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('presupuesto', JSON.stringify(presupuesto));
    localStorage.setItem('listaGastos', JSON.stringify(listaGastos));
}
```

El problema es que cuando recargo la página y la variable presupuesto se carga con el contenido del local storage. Es decir, almacena el objeto de tipo presupuesto guardado en el local storage. Al hacer el siguiente 'submit' e invocar el método presupuesto.gasto() me da el siguiente error:

> app1.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: presupuesto.gasto is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (app1.js:54)

¿Alguien sabe que puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu código, tienes una clase `Presupuesto` con un método `gasto` que es lo que pretendes usar aquí: `presupuesto.gasto(cantidadGasto);`, pero nunca creas una instancia de la clase `Presupuesto`, sino que la variable destinada a `presupuesto` es creada de una forma algo *oscura* dependiendo de una serie de condiciones que tampoco explicas en la pregunta. Quizá sería conveniente que expliques mejor la lógica del programa y que depures en todo momento la variable `presupuesto` para ver tú mismo sobre lo que estás trabajando. Veo algo confuso tu programa.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tu problema es (como te comenta [@A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) no estás creando la instancia de `presupuesto`) que debes crear la instancia de dicha clase.

Por otra parte, [@Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92288/i%c3%b1igo-irigoyen-erquicia), tiene razón en decir que para asignarle un valor a una propiedad de un objeto debes hacerlo como él te comenta.

Sin embargo, ese no es el problema.

En tu clase Presupuesto, tienes un método que se llama `gasto()`, que se encarga de restar la cantidad que recibe como parámetro a la propiedad `restante`.

Me parece que no usas correctamente la variable `presupuesto`. Yo haría lo siguiente:

```js
// VARIABLES
const formulario = document.getElementById('agregar-gasto');
// AQUI SOLO DECLARO 'listaGastos'
var listaGastos = [];


// CLASES
class Presupuesto {

    constructor(presupuesto) {
        this.presupuesto = Number(presupuesto);
        this.restante = Number(presupuesto);
    }

    gasto(cantidad) {
        this.restante -= Number(cantidad);
    }
}

class Gasto {
    constructor(concepto, cuantia) {
        this.concepto = concepto;
        this.cuantia = cuantia;
    }
}


//====================================================
// AHORA DECLARO 'presupuesto' COMO UNA INSTANCIA DE LA CLASE
// LE PASO '0' PARA INSTANCIAR LAS PROPIEDADES

var presupuesto = new Presupuesto(0); // <======


// EVENTOS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // comprobamos si es la primera ejecucion del programa o hay datos en LS
    if(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto') === null) {
        let intro = prompt('¿Cuál es el presupuesto?');
        console.log(typeof(presupuesto) );

    } else {
    
        // ===========================================
        // Aqui debemos hacer uso de la propiedad 'presupuesto'
        presupuesto.presupuesto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto') ); // <======



listaGastos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listaGastos') );
    }

    // actualizamos los datos en pantalla
    actualizaUI();
});

document.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevenimos la accion del HTML

    // leer del formulario de gastos
    const nombreGasto = document.querySelector('#gasto').value;
    const cantidadGasto = document.querySelector('#cantidad').value;

    // comprobar que los gastos no esten vacios, que la cantidad sea un numero positivo
    if(nombreGasto === '' || cantidadGasto === '' || isNaN(cantidadGasto) || cantidadGasto < 0) {
        imprimirMensaje('Hubo un error', 'error');
    } else {


        // ==========================================
        // Ahora esta linea no dará error y a su vez
        // actualizará la propiedad 'restante'
        presupuesto.gasto(cantidadGasto);
        
        
        gasto = new Gasto(nombreGasto, cantidadGasto);
        listaGastos.push(gasto);
        imprimirMensaje('Gasto añadido', 'correcto');
        actualizaUI();
        actualizaLocalStorage();
    }
} ); 


// FUNCIONES
function actualizaUI() {
    const presupuestoSpan = document.querySelector('span#total');
    const restanteSpan = document.querySelector('span#restante');
    const gastosUl = document.querySelector('#gastos ul');

    // imprimir el presupuesto y el restante
    presupuestoSpan.innerHTML = `${presupuesto.presupuesto}`;
    restanteSpan.innerHTML = `${presupuesto.restante}`;

    // comprobar la clase del restante
    if((presupuesto.presupuesto / 4) > presupuesto.restante) {
        const restante = document.querySelector('.restante');
        restante.classList.remove('alert-success', 'alert-warning');
        restante.classList.add('alert-danger');
    } else if ((presupuesto.presupuesto / 2) > presupuesto.restante) {
        const restante = document.querySelector('.restante');
        restante.classList.remove('alert-success');
        restante.classList.add('alert-warning');  
    }

    // imprimir la lista de gastos
    listaGastos.forEach(function(gasto){
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center';
        li.innerHTML = 
            `${gasto.concepto} 
            <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'> $ ${gasto.cuantia} </span>
            `;

        // insertar al HTML
        gastosUl.appendChild(li);
    } );
}

function imprimirMensaje(mensaje, tipo) {
    const divMensaje = document.createElement('div');
    divMensaje.classList.add('text-center', 'alert');

    if(tipo === 'error') {
        divMensaje.classList.add('alert-danger');
    } else {
        divMensaje.classList.add('alert-success');
    }

    divMensaje.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mensaje));
    // insertar en el DOM
    document.querySelector('.primario').insertBefore(divMensaje, formulario);
    // quitar el alert despues de dos segundos
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.primario .alert').remove();
        formulario.reset();
    }, 2000);
}

function actualizaLocalStorage() {

    // =============================================
    // Aqui actualizamos usando la propiedad 'presupuesto'
    // Solo se almacena el valor de la propiedad, no el objeto completo
    localStorage.setItem('presupuesto', JSON.stringify(presupuesto.presupuesto)); // <=====
    localStorage.setItem('listaGastos', JSON.stringify(listaGastos));
}
```

Espero que con estas correcciones se resuelva el problema que tienes.

Cualquier duda puedes preguntar con confianza.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es porque estas intentando asignarle el valor gasto al presupuesto de manera errónea.

Para asignarle el valor a un dato del objeto tienes que hacerlo así:

```
presupuesto.gasto = cantidadGasto;
```

Al ponerle los paréntesis el lo interpreta como función y por eso intenta ejecutar la función. En cambio con este cambio ya no te dará ese error.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage de javascript no guarda objetos, solo guarda datos primitivos como números o strings o booleanos. Para guardar un objeto lo que debes hacer es usar `JSON.stringify`. Esto asumo que ya lo estas haciendo pero lo que pareces no tener claro es que conviertes todo a string y al hacer eso las funciones ya no serán funciones, cuando obtienes el **valor** (no es objeto) del localstorage tu le haces un `JSON.parse` y así es como debe hacerse, pero al convertir un objeto con `JSON.parse` solo te lo hace con las variables primitivas objetos y arreglos, las funciones no las puede "restaurar". Una forma es usando la funcion `eval` pero por varias razones esta función tiene problemas de seguridad y no te lo recomiendo. Otra forma es agregar un constructor en tu objeto desde json, te dejo un vínculo de como hacerlo:

[Como guardar un objeto en localstorage e instanciarlo correctamente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955965/how-come-json-cant-save-objects-functions)